# radix sort to sort some words like dictionary?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, radix

How do I use [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) to sort the the words like in dictionary if the words are of different length?
If the words length are equal than its easy. But I cant figure what to do when it have different lengths?

Comment: hash it into a version of same length

Comment: One thing you could do is pad all of the words with spaces on the right so they're all the same length. Any particular reason you need to use radix sort?

Comment: Why wouldn't you consider "padding" the shorter words with spaces?

Comment: With Jim's suggestion you don't literally have to pad the words - in your implementation you can just assume that any position beyond the actual length is a space, say. You'll need to know a max length, obviously.

Comment: Build a true radix tree, with N characters per node (where N is variable, and is the length of the "common text").  For terminal nodes "AAA" sorts before "AAAA" and after "AA".  (Though, strictly speaking, you'd never have all three -- just a node "AA" with two children, one the terminal and the other "A" with two children -- one terminal and the other"A".)

Comment: I think that "Tries" can be used to do this.